# Guardar datos en txt recorriendo un select

Tags: c#

Necesito desarrollar un programa que guarde el resultado de un `select` en dos variables y guarde los datos en un txt y muestre por consola la iteracion resultante de las url

Ya pude lograr que se imprima en consola correctamente, me podrían indicar como guardar el resultado de la iteracion en un txt, que por cada linea se escriba una url con un salto de linea.

```
  namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string url1 = null;


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=SQL2014;database=ventas;integrated security = true");
                string strSQL = "select  Numero,Terreno "+
                                "FROM datos";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                          while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string resultadoNumero = reader["Numero"].ToString();
                    string resultadoTerreno = reader["Terreno"].ToString();

     url1 = "http://ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Pedidos" + resultadoNumero + resultadoTerreno;


                    Console.WriteLine(url1);


                }
                reader.Close();
                con.Close();
               Console.ReadLine();
           }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, debido a que no especificas que tipo de programa quieres hacer (consola, windows form, etc), que tipo de base de datos, inclusive el **código que tienes avanzado** (lo más importante). Te recomiendo que ingreses a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que entiendas como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Hola, disculpa, si exactamente es por consola y el motor de bases de datos es Sql Server

Comment: Te puedo recomendar que en tu proyecto de consola invoques a una consulta de base de datos (o a través de procedimiento almacenado) y que luego con el resultado empieces a generar el listado de cadenas (en el formato que necesites, tu Url y Parámetros) para que después lo guardes en un archivo TXT. Como podrás leer, es un montón de cosas que se tiene que hacer (demasiado amplia). Revisa: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Te lo agradeceria asi puedo avanzar y despegar mis dudas pero con algo armado. muchas gracias

Comment: Estuve revisando el codigo y siempre me trae el valor de las variables en cero, tantas veces como existan registros en la tabla, pero siempre en cero

Comment: Primero, cambia el tipo de las variables y debes asignarle el valor del SqlDataReader. Por ejemplo: `string numero = reader["Numero"].ToString()`, para luego unirlo a tu Url. Ahora en ningún momento estás recuperando su valor del SqlDataReader si te das cuenta.

Comment: Gracias, ya realice la modificación, me resta que se imprima en pantalla sin la necesidad que oprima una tecla para pasar de iteracion en iteracion y luego comenzaria a guardar el resultado en un txt.

Comment: Ya pude lograr que se imprima en consola correctamente, me podrían indicar como guardar el resultado de la iteracion en un txt, que por cada linea se escriba una url con un salto de linea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías considerar lo siguiente:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = null;
    string strSQL = "select  Numero, Terreno FROM datos";

    string rutaArchivo = @"C:\miArchivo.txt";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=SQL2014;database=ventas;integrated security = true");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string resultadoNumero = reader["Numero"].ToString();
        string resultadoTerreno = reader["Terreno"].ToString();

        url = "http://ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Pedidos" + resultadoNumero + resultadoTerreno;

        Console.WriteLine(url);
        builder.Append(url).AppendLine();
    }

    reader.Close();
    con.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Creando archivo");
    File.WriteAllText(rutaArchivo, builder.ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Donde, la variable `builder` almacenará todas las Urls que se construyen y con el método `File.WriteAllText` creará (en caso no exista) el archivo y escribirá  todo el texto.

*PD. No te olvides de hacer las referencias necesarias.*

---

**Referencia:**

- [Método File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Clase StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, funciona perfecto